# Integrating the Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-login

Refering to 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android?sdk=maven
this page, i try to add Firebase-Facebook login form to my application.

However, when i tried to put the code

`[implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)']` into build.gradle's
dependencies, my android studio gave a message which is below this sentence.

> Error:(24, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()' Possible
>   causes:
>
> The project 'FirebaseTest' may be using a version of
>   the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g.
>   'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0). Upgrade
>   plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project
>
> The project
>   'FirebaseTest' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain
>   the method. Open Gradle wrapper
>   file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

So, I tried to install the sdk in person by download the sdk file, but i don't know how to i install the downloaded file to android studio.

My android studio's version is 2.3.3 and 
my application's compileSdkVersion is 26 and buildToolsVersion is "27.0.1".

Comment: Have you checked, as mentioned in error message, that you're using at least v2.3.3 of gradle plugin (as specified in your root `build.gradle` file)

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
```

Answer (score 0):

add gradle

```
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

add this line in activity - `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);`

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

clickListner of button

```
btnLoginFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


            // Set permissions
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                    LoginActivity.this,
                    Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));


            //  Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_mobile_phone"));


            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                            System.out.println("Success");


                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(
                                                JSONObject json,
                                                GraphResponse response) {


                                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                                // handle error
                                                System.out
                                                        .println("ERROR");
                                            } else {
                                                System.out
                                                        .println("Success");
                                                try {

                                                    String jsonresult = String
                                                            .valueOf(json);
                                                    System.out
                                                            .println("JSON Result"
                                                                    + jsonresult);


                                                    String str_id = json
                                                            .getString("id");
                                                    String str_firstname = json
                                                            .getString("first_name");
                                                    String str_lastname = json
                                                            .getString("last_name");

                                                    String str_email = "";
                                                    try {
                                                        str_email = json
                                                                .getString("email");
                                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                        Log.e("tag", "email not found");
                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                                    } finally {

                                                    Log.e("tag", "------------------FB----------------------------");
                                                    Log.e("tag", "idFacebook=" + str_id);
                                                    Log.e("tag", "first_name=" + str_firstname);
                                                    Log.e("tag", "last_name=" + str_lastname);
                                                    Log.e("tag", "email=" + str_email);

                                                    Log.e("tag", "----------------------------------------------");


                                                    //firebase code
                                                    }
                                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,first_name,last_name,gender");


                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            Log.d("TAG_CANCEL", "On cancel");

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                            Log.d("TAG_ERROR", error.toString());

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
```

}

for more help refer [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)